# Linux bridge device and ARP problems on Hyper-V

Tags: linux, hyper-v, bridge, arp

The following setup:

[image]

I debug with `tcpdump -e -n -i eth1` on both guests.

**Running `arping -I br0 10.0.2.0 -s 10.0.1.0` on guest 1.**

*guest 1:*

```
13:10:51.933237 [guest1-br0-mac] > Broadcast, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.2.0 (Broadcast) tell 10.0.1.0, length 28
```

*guest 2:* nothing!

(It's the same the other way round).

**Running `arping -I eth1 10.0.2.0 -s 10.0.1.0` on guest 1 (eth1 instead of br0):**

*guest 1:*

```
13:13:57.593789 [guest1-eth1-mac] > Broadcast, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.2.0 (Broadcast) tell 10.0.1.0, length 28
```

*guest 2:*

```
13:13:57.594041 [guest1-eth1-mac] > Broadcast, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 10.0.2.0 (Broadcast) tell 10.0.1.0, length 28
13:13:57.594111 [guest2-br0-mac] > [guest1-eth1-mac], ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 10.0.2.0 is-at [guest2-br0-mac], length 28
```

So guest 2 seems to respond, but this response doesn't get back to guest 1.

**I don't understand two things:**

1. Why is there a difference between using `br0` and `eth1` as source interface? Shouldn't the bridge device forward the arp broadcast to `eth1`?
2. What could be the reason for loosing the response of guest 2 in the second test?

   ```
   $ brctl show
   bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled  interfaces
   br0          8000.0123456789AB  no           eth1
   ```

Please tell me what additional information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling "MAC address spoofing" in Hyper-V did the trick! I feel so silly, I wasted two days figuring this out...

**Explanation:**

*1. Question:* When MAC address spoofing is forbidden in Hyper-V, then the source mac address in the Ethernet frame must mach the interfaces mac address. When sending the arp request from interface `br0` this is not the case and Hyper-V drops the frame.

*2. Question:* This is essentially the same problem. Using `eth1` as source interface the request now successfully reaches `eth1` on the other guest and from there `br0`. `br0` now answers the request, but the frame is dropped again by Hyper-V, because the source address does not match `eth1`'s mac address.

MAC address spoofing can be enabled in the virtual network adapter settings. Also see [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458341.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Your solution would be more useful to other readers with a similar problem if you could expand your answer a little to explain how you did this and why it solved the problem.

Comment: Right, thanks for reminding me. I expanded the answer with explanations.